# Weapon RPS - circular list; troubles keeping circular list balanced when expanding

Tags: rock-paper-scissors

I've got a idea for a game in the works, and I'm trying to figure out how to sort 17 weapons into a circular list where each weapon beats the 8 below it but loses to the 8 above it. Currently, I only have an RPS-5 figured out where each beats the 2 below it but loses to the 2 above it:

- bow
- daggers
- magical orb
- gun
- glaive

I then set out to try to expand it into an RPS-7, starting by adding one weapon and creating a placeholder spot to find the most appropriate weapon for. I came up with "spear", which I determined beats "magical orb" and "glaive" but loses to "bow", "daggers", and "gun". What with "gun" being smack between the two things that "spear" beats though, where do I put the placeholder spot? I'm assuming if it's even possible without giving up on my well thought reasons for why what beats what I'll need more than 1 placeholder spot to find an appropriate weapon for.

Is it at all possible to place the placeholder spots such that "spear" ends up above "magical orb" and "glaive" while still being below "bow", "daggers", and "gun"? Or will I have to either alter an interaction or see if I can create a perfectly imbalanced RPS?

If this question would benefit from additional tags, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [10 weapon types, 2 proficiencies, rock-paper-scissors relationship?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120647/10-weapon-types-2-proficiencies-rock-paper-scissors-relationship)

Comment: I made this into a separate question because I was pretty sure that it handled a different question if about the same topic; the first one was about how to make a balanced RPS in the first place, and this one is about how to sort it out when the interactions you've decided on seem hard if not impossible to sort out and present in a simple and easy to understand manner. In case this really is a duplicate though, how can I merge the data from this question into the original question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have a single list that satisfies the conditions you want. One option is to reconsider your weapon types such that the new one you add between daggers and magical orb actually beats magical orb, gun, and glaive and loses to bow and daggers.

Otherwise if you want more complex pairings then a simple list is not the best data structure. A more appropriate data structure is a table. A table would allow you to define the interaction of each weapon type against each other weapon type, so you can make any kind of connection between any two weapons.

```
               Bow   Daggers   Spear   MagicalOrb  Gun   Glaive
Bow             0       1        1         1       -1      -1
Daggers        -1       0        1         1        1      -1
Spear          -1      -1        0         1       -1       1      
MagicalOrb     -1      -1       -1         0        1       1
Gun             1      -1        1        -1        0       1
Glaive          1       1       -1        -1       -1       0
```

You can read this table like the row is Player1 and the column is Player2, -1 means Player2 wins, 1 means Player1 wins, and 0 means it's a draw.

Comment: I was rather stumped trying to sort things into a simple circular list, so I will probably have to use that style of table. Once I have everything sorted out I may attempt to see if there's any way to untangle it into a circular list; if you look up "RPS-101" there's some guy that made 101 rock-paper-scissors throws and sorted them into an easy-to-understand circular chart. I was hoping to be able to emulate that simplicity, but if it really is impossible then I'll just have to hope that this chart style is still simple enough to understand at a glance. Thank you for the idea (;